# variables declared in for-statments appear to be global

Tags: javascript, global-variables

This tripped me up yesterday where I had weird behaviour in a recursive function. I managed to reproduce in and also noticed other behaviour. Basically, the **i** variable in the below html/js appears to be global. The output is 4, then 5. I use FF 40.0.2. The same problem occured in the latest version of Node.js as of last week (ish). I haven't noted the version number for it.

What gives? Is it supposed to behave like this? The problem goes away I I declare the loop-variable just above each of the for-statements.

```
<head>
  <script>

    function foo(recurse)
    {
      if (recurse)
      {
        for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        {
          foo(false);   
          console.log(i);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {}
      }
    }

    foo(true);

  </script>
</head>
```

Expected output:

```
0
1
```

Actual output:

```
4
```

Unsure what to tag this.

Comment: In JavaScript, anything undeclared will be stored in Global(window) object.
Try console.log(window.i), you will know.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is that you *didn't **declare*** them, so they're [implicitly global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Make them [`var`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

```
function foo(recurse) {
  if (recurse) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
//       ^^^
      foo(false);
      console.log(i);
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {}
//       ^^^
  }
}

foo(true);
```

You might also try [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), where you'd get an unhandled error `Assignment to unresolved reference in strict mode code: i`.

Comment: I'd like to put `var i` before `for-loop`, as var use function scope, declare in `for-loop` seems to misleading people that the `i` is only visible in the `for loop` block.

Comment: @fuyushimoya: any js programmer knows that `var` is function-scoped :-)